# Scroll hacia un div de otra pagina usando router navigate angular 4

Tags: html, angular

Estoy haciendo un menu de navegación, en el cual utilizo router.navigate de angular, lo cual funciona correctamente. Sin embargo no se como hacer para que cuando de click en el primer elemento de a barra de navegacion se direccione ala pagina y se haga scroll hacia un div que tengo.

Aquí mi codigo:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">

        <ul class="ulderecho nav navbar-nav">
            <li style="border: none;">
                <a (click)="this.router.navigate(['/contactanos']">Ayuda</a>
            </li>
            <li style="border: none;">
                <a (click)="this.router.navigate(['/inicio'])">Inicio</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Como pueden ver tengo dos elementos llamados ayuda e inico los cuales se dirigen a dos paginas web que ya tengo hecho.

Cuando se haga click en Ayuda ademas de que se direccione a la pagina de ayuda quiero que me haga scroll hacia un div que se encuentra a la mitad de la pagina de ayuda, este div se llama "ayudaDiv".

Como puedo agregar el scroll a la ruta de navegacion.

Comment: fijate si este hilo te sirve https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290014/1423096

Answer (score 1):

Pregunta del OP: Como direccionar a una pagina y se haga scroll hacia un div que tengo?

Una vez que se redireccione a la pagina puedes ir al div que quieras, ejemplo:

```js
setTimeout(function() {

  location.href = "#irMedio";
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

#arriba {
  background-color: blue;
}

#medio {
  background-color: red;
}

#abajo {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#irArriba">arriba</a>
<a href="#irMedio">medio</a>
<a href="#irAbajo">abajo</a>


<div id="arriba">
  <a name="irArriba"></a>
</div>
<div id="medio">
  <a name="irMedio"></a>
</div>
<div id="abajo">
  <a name="irAbajo"></a>
</div>
```

Notese que cada div tiene  `<a name=""></a>`